# Taking screenshot in Objective-C without losing quality

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, screenshot

What I'm trying to achieve is taking a screenshot in my app which is working fine, but the quality is very poor, and the size of the screenshot is also pretty small. I also try to crop the bottom of the image as I did for the top, but I cannot see where I can add dimensions for the bottom. Is there a better way to do this? I'm using the code below:

```
// Define the dimensions of the screenshot you want to take (the entire screen in this case)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *sourceImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //now we will position the image, X/Y away from top left corner to get the portion we want
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [sourceImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, -10)];
    UIImage *croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(croppedImage,nil, nil, nil);
```

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I think you could be missing this - `CGContextClipToRect (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),captureFrame);` Try the solution in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679787/objective-c-capture-screenshot-of-all-views-within-custom-frame).

Answer (score 4):

replace

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
```

with

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
```

Comment: Great! that did the trick for the quality :) Do you also know how I can crop the bottom? Thanks!

Comment: Just use `CGContextClipToRect(curContext, CGRectMake(/*bottom rect*/);`

Comment: Thnx @simalone, how can I use this? I'm gettin errors.

Comment: Where does curContext stand for?

Comment: @Jan `CGContextRef curContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();`, you can replace curContext with `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`

Comment: hmmm, still not got it working, I have now the following code: `// Define the dimensions of the screenshot you want to take (the entire screen in this case)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    CGContextRef curContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClipToRect(curContext, CGRectMake(-10, -10, -10, -10));
    UIImage *sourceImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();`

Comment: (-10, -10, -10, -10) is the rect you want to clip?

Comment: Don't know, just want to crop the bottom hehe

Comment: It works for me for my poor quality custom snapshot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use to save the contents of a view to 2 png files (low and high resolution) onto the desktop.

```
// High resolution
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(drawView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
[[drawView layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *ViewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(ViewImage);
[pngData writeToFile:@"/Users/_username_/Desktop/Image@2x.png" atomically:NO];

// Low resolution
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawView.bounds.size);
[[drawView layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
ViewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(ViewImage);
[pngData writeToFile:@"/Users/_username_/Desktop/Image.png" atomically:NO];
```